# jQuery clone iterative divs on hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, clone, each

I have a series of divs that I want to clone and show/hide on hover to a different div. Although I've figured out how to clone one *or* all with jQuery, I'm quite stuck on how to clone each iteratively.

The HTML, essentially:

```
<div id="test">
  <div id="source1" class="src">content1</div>
  <div id="source2" class="src">content2</div>
  <div id="source3" class="src">content3</div>      
</div>

<div id="dest"></div>
```

I'm thinking the answer probably involves an *each* function; however the following script errors with "second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array" for jquery.min.js:

```
$(".src").hover(function() {
 $(".src").each(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#dest');
  return false;
  $('#dest').show();        
 }, function() {
  $('#dest').hide();
  $('#dest').html('');
 });
});
```

This bit does work nicely to clone *every* (not each) .src div on hover, however:

```
$('.src').hover(function() {
    $('.src').clone().appendTo('#dest');
    $('#dest').show();
}, function() {
    $('#dest').hide();
    $('#dest').html('');
});
```

So, to recap, I want each .src div to be cloned to the #dest div when I hover over it, then disappear when I mouse out. Then the next .src div should do the same thing on hover, and so on...without a separate script for each sourceN div. Please, oh wise ones, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, you need to make use of the $(this) notation.

```
$('.src').hover(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#dest');
    $('#dest').show();
}, function() {
    $('#dest').hide();
    $('#dest').html('');
});
```

Comment: Yowza. So fast and simple. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When cloning the div dont make a use the class selector `'.src'` just use `this` and it should work with only the hovered div

```
$('.src').hover(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#dest');
    $('#dest').show();
}, function() {
    $('#dest').hide();
    $('#dest').html('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsb2A/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test div').bind({
   mouseenter: function(){
       $('#dest').append($(this).clone());
   },
   mouseleave: function(){
       $('#dest #'+$(this).attr('id')).remove()
   }
});
```

Is it ok?

Comment: That's what I understood. My Englih isn't well. Here a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/rF4s4/

Comment: Thanks! This does work on the simplified html sample I provided, but doesn't seem to work on my live site. Maybe because of the remove ID?

Comment: Maybe I forgot a ';' after 'remove()'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.src').hover(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#dest');
    $('#dest').show();
}, function() {
    $('#dest').hide();
    $('#dest').html(''); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Great minds think alike -- you and rkw. Yes, this (this) works.